# find fields in Matlab structures

Tags: matlab

say I have a large structure with lots of names (e.g. 'a', 'b', etc). Given a name and without knowing the index of that particular name, I would like to find that name, similar to the find() command so that I can write additional fields to it

```
dat.name = 'a'
dat(2).name = 'b'
...
dat(26).name = 'z'

dat.name == 'a'

% MATLAB error
Error using  == 
Too many input arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undersand corretly, you want to find an index/indexes in struct array for which name field has given value? If yes, you can do as follows:

```
indexes = find(strcmp({dat(:).name}, 'a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of fields in a struct (as a cell array of strings), use:

```
fields(myStruct)
```

To access the value of a field where the name of the field is held in a variable (as a string), use:

```
myStruct.(fieldName)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your strings are one-character, you can use

```
>> find([dat.name] == 'b') %// concat into a single string (character vector)

ans =

     2
```

If the strings may have any number of characters:

```
>> [temp{1:numel(dat)}] = deal(dat.name);  %// build a cell array of strings
>> find(strcmp(temp,'b'))

ans =

     2
```

Comment: this works also, but I prefer the one-liner recommended by Marcin. Thanks though